# SQL Execution preferring scan over seek

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I am writing a simple query to find a date range. I expect a seek execution plan but continue to get a scan. 
I've simplified but get the undesired result

[image: Execution plan scan over seek]:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.[Date]
FROM PurchaseListT as p
WHERE p.[Date] >= '20180507' AND p.[Date] < '20180524'
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the DDL (`create table ...`). We need to undestand what's the primary key, foreign keys, indexes, and constraints the table has.

Comment: Try adding Non-Clustered Index on Date Column to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you probably do not have a Non-Clustered Index on your Date field.

You'll notice your query plan shows a Clustered Index Scan.  I doubt your Clustered Index is on the Date field, it is Probably on your Id field.

Without an index on the Date field, there is nothing for the engine to SEEK.  Instead it is going through the clustered index, and for each entry evaluating if the Date value fits your WHERE clause (this is a scan).

If you do, in fact, have an index on Date, the optimizer may have decided that based on your table size that it is still faster to SCAN the Clustered Index than to SEEK the Non-Clustered and then look-up the other requested column values from the Clustered Index.  This is another indication that you simply do not have the index on Date, because it would mean you have Clustered Index on something other than Id. An unlikely scenario given you requested only Id and Date and the plan performs the Clustered Index SCAN rather than a table scan.